# Why is this ASP.NET Core POST Request Returning "405 (Method Not Allowed)"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a very simple API created using ASP.NET Core 2.1. When a client page calls the API from localhost:8080, the API located at localhost:5000 returns HTTP:405.

Why? Note that the HTTP GET test method in AuthController.cs works just as expected. It is only the HTTP POST request returning HTTP:405.

**Controllers\AuthController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using server.Models;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace server.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/auth")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet, Route("test")]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        [HttpPost, Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid client request");
            }

            if (user.UserName == "johndoe" && user.Password == "def@123")
            {
                var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"));
                var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "http://localhost:5000",
                    audience: "http://localhost:5000",
                    claims: new List<Claim>(),
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),
                    signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                );

                var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
                return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Models\LoginModel.cs**

```
namespace server.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set;}
        public string Password { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;

namespace server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5000",
                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5000",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
                };
            });

            var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
            corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
            corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("SiteCorsPolicy", corsBuilder.Build());
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors("SiteCorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

**index.html (localhost:8080)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JWT Auth</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Output:</p>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var item =  {
                UserName: "johndoe",
                Password: "def@123" 
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                accepts: "application/json",
                url: '/api/auth/Login',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Something went wrong!");
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log('Testing');
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the server logs for the request?

Comment: Sounds like a CORS problem, did you enable CORS for the localhost:8080 endpoint?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have added Startup.cs. It contains the CORS configuration.

Comment: That CORS configuration is invalid, AllowCredentials is not compatible with AllowAnyOrigin: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto could you provide an example as an answer to the question?

Comment: You already have the answer commented out: `//corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:56573")` (wrong port, though, that should have been `corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have updated Startup.cs in the question. It is still returning HTTP:405.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be `Stringify`ing the data in the POST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are POSTing to /api/auth/login, but on the server you are hosting your page from (that would be localhost:8080). Did you mean to POST that to http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login?

Comment: You're right! I have changed the URL in the JavaScript. Now I am getting:  POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your login controller action. Screams like you not getting LoginModel deserialized (and it is null). Your own code returns that.